Transaction comes up on history but does not show crypto type, wallet balance not updated though
I received a USDT transfer through the Solana network on my Binance account.
Transaction history shows the transaction as a number with no unit behind (doesn't say USDT), unlike other transaction histories which show both number and unit.
My wallet balance does not show any increase in amount as well.
I checked the Txn ID on Solscan, and it shows that transaction is a "Success: Finalized (Max Confirmations)".
What is happening? Can the sender burn the token after transaction succeeds?
